# Remote VNC from Mac in to Linux machine only shows top left corner of the Linux machine

Tags: linux, mac, remote-desktop, vnc

I only have access to the top left corner of the desktop and cannot enlarge the screen to view the rest of the Linux machine desktop. I can still move things around and click things within that small area, but I can't view or access the rest of the desktop. I have tried multiple ways to remote into the Linux machine (native mac OS VNC, VNC viewer) and the result has been the same so I think it has something to do with the Linux machine I am trying to remote into.

I do not know much about the Linux machine itself but I am running a Macbook Pro on Ventura.

Is there some way to fix this so I can see the whole desktop of the Linux machine when I remote in?
Ideally I will not need direct access to the Linux machine, but I can get access if that is necessary.

Let me know if more information is necessary. Thanks

what the screen looks like when using native mac screen share and also "zoomed out"

[image: what the screen looks like when using native mac screen share and also "zoomed out"]